# Cannot upgrade aurora-postgresql from 9.6.9 to 10.7

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-aurora

I'm running AWS Aurora PostgreSQL cluster with aurora-postgresql engine 9.6.9 in a single instance of db.r4.large.
Now, I want to upgrade my Aurora Postgresql to engine 10.7.

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Upgrading.html

AWS documentation suggests that upon Modify DB cluster should do the trick to upgrade. However, there isn't any PostgreSQL compatible with 10.x in the dropdown.

Terraform: On changing the engine version from 9.6.9 to 10.7, only deletes the current 9.6.9 db instance from the cluster but doesn't create new 10.7 db instance.

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "test" {
...
  engine            = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version    = "10.7" # old 9.6.9
...

}
```

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "test_cluster_instances" {
  count = 1
  cluster_identifier           = "${aws_rds_cluster.test.id}"
  instance_class               = "db.r4.large"
  engine                       = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version               = "10.7" # old 9.6.9
...
}
```

terraform plan:

```
  ~ update in-place  
-/+ destroy and then create replacement  

Terraform will perform the following actions:  

  ~ aws_rds_cluster.test  
      engine_version:                  "9.6.9" => "10.7"  

-/+ aws_rds_cluster_instance.test_cluster_instances (new resource required)  
      id:                              "test-0" => <computed> (forces new resource)  
      apply_immediately:               "true" => "true"  
      arn:                             "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:xxxxxx:db:test-0" => <computed>  
      auto_minor_version_upgrade:      "false" => "false"  
      availability_zone:               "us-east-1a" => <computed>  
      cluster_identifier:              "test" => "test"  
      copy_tags_to_snapshot:           "true" => "true"  
      db_parameter_group_name:         "default.aurora-postgresql9.6" <computed>  
      db_subnet_group_name:            "test_db" => "test_db"  
      dbi_resource_id:                 "db-QDIHAS6J2MLMVKHVUENDTFWQJE" => <computed>   
      endpoint:                        "xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" => <computed>  
      engine:                          "aurora-postgresql" => "aurora-postgresql"  
      engine_version:                  "9.6.9" => "10.7" (forces new resource)  
      identifier:                      "test-0" => "test-0"  
      identifier_prefix:               "" => <computed>  
      instance_class:                  "db.r4.large" => "db.r4.large"  
      kms_key_id:                      "" => <computed>  
      monitoring_interval:             "0" => "0"  
      monitoring_role_arn:             "" => <computed>  
      performance_insights_enabled:    "false" => "false"  
      performance_insights_kms_key_id: "" => <computed>  
      port:                            "5432" => <computed>  
      preferred_backup_window:         "03:00-04:00" => <computed>  
      preferred_maintenance_window:    "sun:03:00-sun:04:00" => "sun:03:00-sun:04:00"  
      promotion_tier:                  "0" => "0"  
      publicly_accessible:             "true" => "true"  
      storage_encrypted:               "false" => <computed>  
      tags.%:                          "1" => "1"  
      tags.instance:                   "test-0" => "test-0"  
      writer:                          "true" => <computed>  


Plan: 1 to add, 1 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

On running terraform apply got the following errors:

```
aws_rds_cluster.test: Modifying... (ID: test)
  engine_version: "9.6.9" => "10.7"
aws_rds_cluster_instance.test_cluster_instances: Still destroying... (ID: test-0, 10s elapsed)
aws_rds_cluster_instance.test_cluster_instances: Still destroying... (ID: test-0, 3m40s elapsed)
aws_rds_cluster_instance.test_cluster_instances: Still destroying... (ID: test-0, 3m50s elapsed)
...
...
aws_rds_cluster_instance.test_cluster_instances: Destruction complete after 3m54s


Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:


* aws_rds_cluster.test: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_rds_cluster.test: Failed to modify RDS Cluster (test): InvalidParameterCombination: Cannot upgrade aurora-postgresql from 9.6.9 to 10.7
    status code: 400, request id: c24c4c06-3d98-4ca3-ae95-bf3fd4150959
```

Comment: What did the plan output show before you ran the apply?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR
Terraform plan is as expected:  
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.  
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:  
  ~ update in-place  
-/+ destroy and then create replacement  

Terraform will perform the following actions:    
  
  ~ aws_rds_cluster.test    
      engine_version:                  "9.6.9" => "10.7"  
  
-/+ aws_rds_cluster_instance.test_cluster_instances (new resource required)  
  
  
Plan: 1 to add, 1 to change, 1 to destroy.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the plan output please?

Comment: updated question. sorry for bad formatting. Thanks

Comment: Hi @krtsh did you find an answer for this?

Comment: FYI, the [top answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58381414/15454208) (by Derek) is out of date now - [as of March 2020](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/03/amazon-aurora-with-postgresql-compatibility-supports-in-place-upgrade-from-96-to-10/), AWS Aurora Postgres supports in-place major version upgrades from 9.6 -> 10

Answer (score 4):

The AWS documentation is not as clear as it could be, but currently it is impossible to do a major version upgrade on Aurora e.g. you can upgrade from 9.6.9 to 9.6.12, but you cannot upgrade from 9.6.9 to 10.7 without dumping all of the data, creating a new 10.7 instance and restoring it there.

Amazon claims that they are working on upgrade path, but they refuse to say when it will be available, it could be announced at this year's Re:Invent, next year or even later.

This is sad, because as we are talking about 9.6.9, PostgreSQL 12.0 was just  released.

To be frank, I would not use RDS for anything important, it is always behind with features (now 3 major versions behind), you only can use extensions that are approved by Amazon, solutions for failover and streaming backups are available in and are open sourced. The only reason to use RDS/Aurora is the management of it, but being in ops, PG (unlike mysql) is quite solid I don't remember any issues with it. It might require some to tune settings, but RDS/Aurora doesn't free you from that either.

Answer (score 1):

As at 17 Oct 2019 (as [Derek suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58381414/1101109), there are [other ways to do](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/a4clwz/how_do_i_upgrade_aurora_postgres_from_v969_to_v10/ebenvpd/) it depending on your application requirements):

> **Note**
>
> Aurora PostgreSQL does not currently support in-place major version upgrades. To migrate a database from one major version to another you can use dump and load tools such as the PostgreSQL utilities [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) and [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html).

Source (as linked by [@krtsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8093701/krtsh)): https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Upgrading.html